# Installation Problem

Tags: installation, wolfram-player

I am I was running Mathematica 13 and Mathematica 6 on a Windows 10 Pro desktop. Just recently I deleted Mathematica Player in an effort to save space on my C: drive. So now when I try to open a notebook I get the following error message: "There was a syntax error on the LinkSetup file "C:\Users\JOELM\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\FrontEnd\init.m"
Does this mean I have to re-install Mathematica Player?

Comment: Somebody might have insight here, but this and similar questions are best addressed to [Wolfram Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

Comment: Look at your init.m file. There is something wrong in this initialization file. May be a reference to the Player.